# Things to consider while failproofing socket communciation

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling, network-programming

I have a simple client/server socket program written in python. So far I think I have managed to deal with two types of certain socket errors.

- server is not alive when the client is open (Connectionrejected)
- server shuts down while the client is open (Connectionreset)

I am wondering what other errors I should be accounting for. When the client sends a message and the server is closed before the send happens, the client waits until it can reconnect and sends the message however I am not sure if that covers all the cases where the message can be lost or not transmitted completely.

server.py

```
import socket 
import threading

HEADER = 8
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "127.0.0.1" #socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "exit"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind(ADDR)


def close():
    server.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    server.close()
    print ("closed")


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Barcode received".encode(FORMAT))
    conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    conn.close()
        

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}")



print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import datetime
import time


HEADER = 8
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "exit"
SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)


def check_connection(ADDR):
    print("Trying to connect to the server...")
    connected = False
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while not connected:
        try:
            client.connect(ADDR)        
        except socket.error as error:
            connected = False
            time.sleep(0.01)
            print("Can't connect.Retrying...")
            #print(connected)
        else:
            connected = True
            print("Connected to the server")
    return client
        
        
def send(msg,client,ADDR):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    sending = True
    while sending :
        try:
            cl_ls[0].send(send_length)
            cl_ls[0].send(message)
            print(cl_ls[0].recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
            sending = False
        except socket.error as error:
            cl_ls[0] = check_connection(ADDR)
            cl_ls[0].send(send_length)
            cl_ls[0].send(message)
            sending = False
            print(cl_ls[0].recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
        
cl_ls = ["client"]
client = check_connection(ADDR)
cl_ls[0] = client
accept_more_barcodes = True
while accept_more_barcodes:
    input_value = input("Type 'exit' to close input box ")
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    input_value += ' *** ' + date_time
    if (input_value).startswith("exit"):
        accept_more_barcodes = False
    else:  
        with open("barcodes.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(input_value + "\n")
    send(input_value,cl_ls[0],ADDR)
```

Comment: You should expect that any `send` or `recv` call can throw a socket error, and a `recv` call can also return 0 bytes, indicating the end of the connection.

Comment: `recv(n)` can receive less than `n` bytes as well. Buffer received data until you have the number if bytes to complete a message.